# Create grid with bootstrap card component

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a grid using the Bootstrap 4 card component. For this, I have read the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/) and used the `card-deck` option. I want that every row has two columns with a similar behaviour to `col-12 col-md-6`, with the particularity that the second column will also be splited into two rows, each one having an horizontal card. I have this piece of code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card-deck">
            <div class="card">
                <img
                    class="card-img-top"
                    src$="{{getArticleImage2(article1)}}"
                />
                <div class="card-body py-2">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center mb-2">
                        <img class="icon-sm mr-2 img-fluid" src={{getFavIcon(article1)}}>
                        <a class="card-link medium-text" target="_blank" href$="https://{{getSources(article1)}}">
                            {{getSources(article1)}}
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <p class="card-text article-headline medium-text">
                        {{article1.schema:headline}}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <img
                            class="card-img"
                            src$="{{getArticleImage2(article2)}}"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <div class="card-body p-2">
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center mb-2">
                                <img class="icon-sm mr-2 img-fluid" src={{getFavIcon(article2)}}>
                                <a class="card-link medium-text" target="_blank" href$="https://{{getSources(article2)}}">
                                    {{getSources(article2)}}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <p class="card-text article-headline medium-text">
                                {{article2.schema:headline}}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                        
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <img
                            class="card-img"
                            src$="{{getArticleImage2(article2)}}"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <div class="card-body p-2">
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-start align-items-center mb-2">
                                <img class="icon-sm mr-2 img-fluid" src={{getFavIcon(article3)}}>
                                <a class="card-link medium-text" target="_blank" href$="https://{{getSources(article3)}}">
                                    {{getSources(article3)}}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <p class="card-text article-headline medium-text">
                                {{article3.schema:headline}}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that with this disposition I have three cols instead of two. The last two cards are displayed horizontally, but they are not stacked one below the other. [Here](https://www.codeply.com/p/CHooIdPLjL) is a code snippet. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Can you put this code into somewhere that we could see the output?

Comment: how about use `row` or `d-flex` instead of `card-deck`? I think it is simple

Comment: @DemeterDimitri Just added it, sorry

Comment: @AliQorbani Because using card-deck all the cards image, title and body will be aligned and I think it is the preferable way of doing this kind of things with cards. I tried doing it by myself and could not find a propert way.

Answer (score 0):

if you added a div with class `card-columns` like that:

```
<div class="card-deck">
            <div class="card-columns">
                <div class="card">
                    <img
                        class="card-img-top"
                        src=""
                    />
                    <div class="card-body py-2">
                       //.................
```

it will give you two cloumns one with a card displayed vertically and the other contains two horizontal cards.
[image]

Also ***read the last section of the documentation*** maybe it will be helpful for you to specify how many cards included in one column
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/

Comment: I could not achieve that behaviour with the card-columns, so I used actual columns. Do you know how can I make that both columns have the same height?

Comment: Check this https://www.codeply.com/p/5oeqc2EJDE it show the result I got.
About giving colums the same height, give them in css the exact height. for example the vertical card has 400px height so give the others 200px for each or maybe 180px to set 40px margin between them.